# Property [marca] not found on type [com.example.bean.CarBean]]

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jsf, primefaces

first of all, I am writing this because I am desperate. The thing is I was doing a simple Spring Boot CRUD with Primefaces. I used a bean called "carBean" to access the data in the index.xhtml file. Until there everything ok, things started to turn weird from now on. I tried to use a simple inputText to bind a text given in the UI to a property in the bean.
But I was constantly getting error 500, telling me that the property "marca" was not found in the bean, and I have checked 10000 times and everything is OK in there. So I started testing, and eventually I figured out that, the property that was working fine "carBean.cars" if I change the name to whatever I change (and obviously the methods liked to the property), It stop working. Is like the only property that works has to be named "cars". What I am missing here? Is driving me crazy, I promise this was my last resource. Thanks in advance .

carBean

```
package com.example.bean;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.inject.Named;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;

import com.example.controller.CarController;
import com.example.dto.CarDTO;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
@Named("carBean")
@Scope(value = "session")
public class CarBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8338541378806874723L;
    
    @Autowired
    CarController carController;


    private List<CarDTO> cars;


    private Integer id;
    private String marca;
    private String modelo;
    private String precio;
    private String bastidor;
    private String potencia;
    
    
    public String getMarca() {
        return marca;
    }

    public void setMarca(String marca) {
        this.marca = marca;
    }



    public List<CarDTO> getCars() {
        cars =  carController.getAllCars();
        return cars;
        
    }



    public void delete(CarDTO car) {
        carController.deleteCar(car.id);
        cars = carController.getAllCars();
    }

    public void add() {
        CarDTO newCar = new CarDTO();
        newCar.marca = this.marca;
        newCar.modelo = this.modelo;
        newCar.precio = this.precio;
        newCar.bastidor = this.bastidor;
        newCar.potencia = this.potencia;
        carController.create(newCar);
    }
    
    public String redirect() {
        return "index.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
    }


}
```

index.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE xhtml PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"> 

<h:head>
    <h3> REGISTRO DE COCHES </h3>
    <h:form id = "tabla">
        <div class="card">
            <p:dataTable var="car" value="#{carBean.cars}">
            
                <p:column sortBy="#{car.marca}" headerText="Marca">
                    <h:outputText value="#{car.marca}" />
                </p:column>
    
                <p:column  sortBy="#{car.modelo}" headerText="Modelo">
                    <h:outputText value="#{car.modelo}" />
                </p:column>
    
                <p:column sortBy="#{car.precio}" headerText="Precio">
                    <h:outputText value="#{car.precio}" />
                </p:column>
    
                <p:column sortBy="#{car.bastidor}" headerText="Bastidor">
                    <h:outputText value="#{car.bastidor}" />
                </p:column>
                  <p:column sortBy="#{car.potencia}" headerText="Potencia">
                    <h:outputText value="#{car.potencia}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                 <p:commandButton type="submit" value="Eliminar" actionListener="#{carBean.delete(car)}" 
                                  update=":tabla" />
                 <p:commandButton type="button" value="Editar"/>
                </p:column>
                
            </p:dataTable>
             <p:commandButton value="Nuevo Coche" type="submit" oncomplete="PF('createModal').show();"/>
        </div>
    </h:form>
    
    <p:dialog header="Agregar" widgetVar="createModal" id="createModal">
            <h:form id="createDialog">
                <p:panel header="Detalles del coche">
                <h:panelGrid columns="1">
                <h:outputLabel value="Marca:"/>
                <h:inputText id="marca" value="#{carBean.marca}" required="true"> </h:inputText>
                <h:outputLabel value="Modelo"/>
                <h:inputText id="modelo"> </h:inputText>
                <h:outputLabel value="Precio"/>
                <h:inputText id="precio"> </h:inputText>
                <h:outputLabel value="Bastidor"/>
                <h:inputText id="bastidor"> </h:inputText>
                <h:outputLabel value="Potencia"/>
                <h:inputText id="potencia"> </h:inputText>
                </h:panelGrid>
                </p:panel>
            </h:form>
    </p:dialog>
    
    
        
</h:head>
</html>
```

Why I cannot used other property that isn´t called "cars"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mess Lombok `@Data` autogenerated getters and setters with the one you've declared in the Bean.

You have used a getter as a method, which is not a good thing to do because it can be called multiple times, see: [Why JSF calls getters multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090033/why-jsf-calls-getters-multiple-times)

```
public List<CarDTO> getCars() {
    cars =  carController.getAllCars(); // remove business logic from getter
    return cars;      
}
```

Better initialize your `private List<CarDTO> cars` variable in a method annotated with `@PostContruct`

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    cars = carController.getAllCars();
}
```

For more check this example: [PrimeFaces DataTable CRUD](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/crud.xhtml?jfwid=cf9f0)